# raspberry pi zero 2 w usb drive connection to windows 10

Tags: usb, windows

I wanted to use a raspberry pi zero 2 w...as a usb drive stick on windows 10.  So I got a raspberry pi zero 2 w...then I got this device to connect to my usb connection on my windows 10 box:
[https://www.amazon.com/iUniker-Expansion-Breakout-Raspberry-Inserted/dp/B07NKNBZYG/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=iUniker+USB+Dongle+Expansion+Breakout+Module+Kit+for+Raspberry+Pi+Zero%2FW&qid=1639882368&s=electronics&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NKNBZYG)

then I applied a 256gig sd card and followed these instructions:
https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive

I also loaded the ndis driver from here for windows 10:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=USB+RNDIS+Gadget

df -h shows:

/dev/loop0      200G   32K  200G   1% /mnt/usb_share

/mnt/usb_share is the file I formated fat32 and should be able to access.

any ideas: any idea what to check?

Comment: `I got this device to connect to my usb connection` is it compatible with the zero 2? `any ideas` about what?  `any idea what to check?` what is the problem?